# How to get my current timezone name and date with time?

Tags: php

Now date in my country 10.01.2018 and time 10:03. My time zone name is `"Asia/Tashkent"` and if I write in code:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo date('d-m-y H:m');
```

Displayed timezone name: `Europe/Moscow`
Date Time: `10-01-18 08:01`

How I can get my timezone and my current date?

Comment: You have to set the required timezone in php.ini

Comment: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file

Comment: Check above link to set your required timezone in your php.ini file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set it first with [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tashkent");
echo date('d-m-y H:m');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your **[timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set timezone for your time using [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)